# Define what usergroup or user that can authorize UAC

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy

I'm wondering how I can make custom usergroups that is allowed to authorize UAC for installations and changes?

Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition 70+ Clients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UAC only differentiates between administrators of the computer, and standard users. It cannot be delegated - that is - you cannot allow a standard user/non-administrator to approve UAC prompts.

(You can add your own security groups to the local Administrators group on the machine. This will allow members of those custom groups to both be administrators of the computer as well as authorize UAC elevated actions.)

Here are essentially all of the configurable options for UAC. (You can find these in secpol.msc, in Local Policies > Security Options.)

[image: UAC]